# Previous Year record in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, window-functions

How do we get the previous year values in the current row.

example

```
id      year    amount
1001    2001    2400
1002    2003    3600
1003    2005    2300
1002    2004    1600
```

Desired Output

```
id      year    amount  prevyearAmount
1001    2001    2400    Null
1002    2003    3600    2400
1003    2005    2300    1600
1002    2004    1600    3600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*, lag(amount) over (order by year) as prev_year_amount
from t;
```

Note that you are asking for the previous year *with data*, as opposed to the previous year.  In my opinion, you should have `NULL` for 2003 because there is no 2002 in the data.

If that is what you really want, a self-join is easy enough:

```
select t.*, tprev.amount as prev_year_amount
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.year = t.year - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Window function `lag()` does exactly what you ask for:

```
select t.*, lag(amount) over(order by year) prev_amount
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, but the lag function is taking long time since I need to spin it on more than 1 million records

Comment: @sql2020: for this task, `lag()` is the most efficient solution, by far. Other options would require self-joining the table, which will be more expensive.